# SQL List Entity

Tags: sql, list, select, entity

In SQL, is there such a thing as a List. I am thinking of something similar to a table, but only has values that cannot be edited but can be retrieved via a Select statement.

Something like the following:

A List called 'Items', that has the following data:

- Item1
- Item2
- Item3
- Item4

When I call a Select statement on this List, I get the 4 above values.

Does such a thing exist in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might want is a View

(from below link)

Creates a virtual table whose contents (columns and rows) are defined by a query. Use this statement to create a view of the data in one or more tables in the database. For example, a view can be used for the following purposes:

- To focus, simplify, and customize the perception each user has of
     the database
- As a security mechanism by allowing users to access
     data through the view, without granting the users permissions to
     directly access the underlying base tables.
- To provide a backward
     compatible interface to emulate a table whose schema has changed

[SQL Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. Views are something that works as a List but aren't lists. Also, using the "[In](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/in.php)" function can be helpful for that matter. Other than that, I don't think there are lists.